MySQL setting SHARED_READ locks for Consistent Non-locking reads in transaction
I had been playing around my MySQL(version 8.0.19) on how consistent reads and non-locking/locking reads work under transactions with different isolation levels. The documentation mentions that consistent reads are non-locking by default and do not set any table locks.
here

Consistent read is the default mode in which InnoDB processes SELECT statements in READ COMMITTED and REPEATABLE READ isolation levels. A consistent read does not set any locks on the tables it accesses, and therefore other sessions are free to modify those tables at the same time a consistent read is being performed on the table.

And here

SELECT ... FROM is a consistent read, reading a snapshot of the database and setting no locks unless the transaction isolation level is set to SERIALIZABLE. For SERIALIZABLE level

However, when I played around with this locally I noticed that MySQL is setting a SHARED_READ lock even on consistent read when done in a transaction. The database is running with the default isolation level of REPEATABLE-READ and autocommit=1.
Session 1 outside a txn
mysql> select name from user;
+------+
| name |
+------+
| bar  |
| tom  |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

And no lock is set by mysql for this.
mysql> SELECT OBJECT_TYPE, OBJECT_SCHEMA, OBJECT_NAME, LOCK_TYPE, LOCK_STATUS,PROCESSLIST_HOST, PROCESSLIST_TIME, PROCESSLIST_STATE, PROCESSLIST_INFO from performance_schema.metadata_locks INNER JOIN performance_schema.threads ON THREAD_ID = OWNER_THREAD_ID where OBJECT_SCHEMA!='performance_schema';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Inside a txn
mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select name from user;
+------+
| name |
+------+
| bar  |
| tom  |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

Looking at the metadata_locks table now shows the SHARED_READ lock set
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| OBJECT_TYPE | OBJECT_SCHEMA | OBJECT_NAME | LOCK_TYPE   | LOCK_STATUS | PROCESSLIST_HOST | PROCESSLIST_TIME | PROCESSLIST_STATE | PROCESSLIST_INFO      |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| TABLE       | testdb        | user        | SHARED_READ | GRANTED     | localhost        |               81 | NULL              | select name from user |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

But this surprising aspect this even though the lock is set other transactions are not blocked from inserting/deleting/updating rows in the same table.
Session 3
mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into user (name) values ("spam");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> commit;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Looking at the metadata_locks table shows below
mysql> SELECT OBJECT_TYPE, OBJECT_SCHEMA, OBJECT_NAME, LOCK_TYPE, LOCK_STATUS,PROCESSLIST_HOST, PROCESSLIST_TIME, PROCESSLIST_STATE, PROCESSLIST_INFO from performance_schema.metadata_locks INNER JOIN performance_schema.threads ON THREAD_ID = OWNER_THREAD_ID where OBJECT_SCHEMA!='performance_schema';
+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| OBJECT_TYPE | OBJECT_SCHEMA | OBJECT_NAME | LOCK_TYPE    | LOCK_STATUS | PROCESSLIST_HOST | PROCESSLIST_TIME | PROCESSLIST_STATE | PROCESSLIST_INFO                        |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| TABLE       | testdb        | user        | SHARED_READ  | GRANTED     | localhost        |              101 | NULL              | select name from user                   |
| TABLE       | testdb        | user        | SHARED_WRITE | GRANTED     | localhost        |                3 | NULL              | insert into user (name) values ("spam") |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------+

So even though SHARED_READ was in place, the transaction T2 was able to insert new row, which begs the questions

Why this lock was acquired in first place when it defaulted consistent non-locking read?
If it was set anyhow then why it didn't work and let the insert/updates/deletes to go through?

I also tried a locking read with select .. for share and it does work as expected however it also sets the SHARED_READ. See example below
Session 1
mysql> select name from user for share;
+------+
| name |
+------+
| bar  |
| tom  |
| spam |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Session 2:
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into user (name) values ("baz");
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Locks table
+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+
| OBJECT_TYPE | OBJECT_SCHEMA | OBJECT_NAME | LOCK_TYPE    | LOCK_STATUS | PROCESSLIST_HOST | PROCESSLIST_TIME | PROCESSLIST_STATE | PROCESSLIST_INFO                       |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+
| TABLE       | testdb        | user        | SHARED_READ  | GRANTED     | localhost        |               61 | NULL              | select name from user for share        |
| TABLE       | testdb        | user        | SHARED_WRITE | GRANTED     | localhost        |               10 | update            | insert into user (name) values ("baz") |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

So we can see that second transaction was not allowed to update the table since t1 was holding a SHARED_READ lock as part of locking read and this is indeed the expected behavior.
So can someone please help me understand

Why MySQL is setting SHARED_READ locks for consistent reads when issued inside a transaction even though the lock does not seem to work?
The locks for consistent read and locking read seems to be identical then why works as expected and other doesn't ?

Is this happening due to metadata locking to prevent the execution of DDL statements issued from other transactions to ensure data consistency? However, if that's the case then consistent non-locking reads would never happen ?

You are mixing metadata locks with row level locks up. The documentation is talking about row level locks, which you can check in INNODB_LOCKS table.

@Shadow I just realized that this might be happening due to metadata locking but thanks for the pointer to innodb_locks table.

So I did some more digging on it was able to figure out things. So these SHARED_READ are the locks set by metadata locking service my mysql. The hint was within the table name I was querying i.e. metadata_locks.
So the purpose of these metadata locks is to ensure serializability and guard against the data inconsistency issues like DDL statements being issued by other session/transactions while one session/transaction is reading data from it.
The locking behaviour which confused was infact the InnoDB row level locking and thanks to @Shadow for pointing me in the right direction.
And we can check innodb locks by querying the performance_schema.data_locks table like below after I issued select * from user where id=1 for share against user table with
mysql> select OBJECT_SCHEMA, OBJECT_NAME, LOCK_TYPE, LOCK_MODE, LOCK_STATUS, LOCK_DATA, PROCESSLIST_USER, PROCESSLIST_HOST, PROCESSLIST_DB, PROCESSLIST_TIME, PROCESSLIST_STATE, PROCESSLIST_INFO from performance_schema.data_locks as d join performance_schema.threads as th where d.thread_id=th.thread_id;
+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| OBJECT_SCHEMA | OBJECT_NAME | LOCK_TYPE | LOCK_MODE     | LOCK_STATUS | LOCK_DATA | PROCESSLIST_USER | PROCESSLIST_HOST | PROCESSLIST_DB | PROCESSLIST_TIME | PROCESSLIST_STATE | PROCESSLIST_INFO                        |
+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| testdb        | user        | TABLE     | IS            | GRANTED     | NULL      | test             | localhost        | testdb         |                2 | NULL              | select * from user where id=1 for share |
| testdb        | user        | RECORD    | S,REC_NOT_GAP | GRANTED     | 1         | test             | localhost        | testdb         |                2 | NULL              | select * from user where id=1 for share |
+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


The reason we see a single row locked because I queried by primary_key field id in this case, if I change my query to mysql> select * from user where name="foo" for share; innodb would lock all the rows in the table because name is not unique and multiple the rows can have same name set by other transactions.
